# Multiclient Full-duplex Perl socket

Tags: perl, sockets, serversocket

I wrote a multiclient socket script in perl. I am able to make connections with multiple clients using fork. But after a new connection is established i can only send and receive one time. I am not able to further read or write on the client socket, to make an extended conversation.

**AIM:**

After client gets connected it will send its ID to server. AFter receiving the ID, server will fetch the client's file using its ID and send it page by page to the client. As client can only accept limited bytes of data, we cannot send it in a single socket send. So i need to send a 1024 byte of data. Client must acknowledge and again i got to send the next page. Like this i got to make the socket connection for long time simultaneously for every client until they all receive the whole file.

**Code Example:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::INET;

# flush after every write
$| = 1;
my $data;
my ( $server_socket, $client_socket );
my ( $peer_address,  $peer_port );

$server_socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => '192.168.0.7',
    LocalPort => '1008',
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => 5,
    Reuse     => 1
) or die "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

print "SERVER Waiting for client connection on port 1008";
#$SIG{CHLD}=sub {wait()}; # Signal waiting for the Child process created
while ( $client_socket = $server_socket->accept() ) {
    my $pid = fork();    # Creating child as soon client creates a connection
    if ( $pid == 0 )     # Checking the child process
    {
        my $peer_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
        my $peer_port    = $client_socket->peerport();
        print "Accepted New Client Connection From : $peer_address, $peer_port\n";
        $client_socket->recv( $data, 1024 );
        print $data;
        $client_socket->send("FileLine1");

        #Get the acknowledgement
        $client_socket->recv( $data, 1024 );

        $client_socket->send("FileLine2");

        #Get the end acknowledgement
        $client_socket->recv( $data, 1024 );
        exit(0);    # Exiting child process
    }
}
```

My question is: Can we rely on perl for doing it ? or Do we need to go for some other platform like Java etc.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend that you use [Net::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod) CPAN module to build your server.

`Net::Server` attempts to be a generic server. It includes with it the ability to run as an inetd process, a single connection server, a forking server, a preforking server which maintains a constant number of preforked children, or as a managed preforking server which maintains the number of children based on server load.

Comment: I really need some example for 'making a persistent multiclient socket connection' using Net::Server module. I cannot find one